# Handle empty dataframe from read_sql_query with chunk size after the result

Tags: python, pandas

I am connecting to the postgress and running the some sql query and converting to dataframe by using read_sql_query with some chunk size as 10. Its work perfectly when there is data in table but when there is no data its not going into for loop for the next programme.

```
data=pd.read_sql_query("select * from table",connection, chunksize=int(10))

for data in dataframe:
 print(dataframe)
```

If I print data this is the output<generator object SQLiteDatabase._query_iterator at 0x00000254B7491F68>.
How to check <generator object SQLiteDatabase._query_iterator at 0x00000254B7491F68>
is empty before going to for loop.

Comment: I guess, you have interchanged variable name between `data` and `dataframe`. could you confirm that?

Comment: yeah just for the print statement but otherthan that everything is same.. It will be print(data)